# Running ng add @angular/material does nothing

Tags: npm, angular-material

Running `ng add @angular/material` does nothing. I was waiting more than 15min, than I pressed ctrl + c. I tried it from VSC terminal and from cmd. Today I installed the newest version of node.js and npm. Of course, I restarted my PC and VSC. Is this an issue of angular/material or npm, or something different? What can I do to identify the source problem? Does anyone have an idea?

***[EDIT]***
I have news. Today `ng add @angular/material` works as expected. Maybe I had a network issue. Yesterday I worked via VPN in home-office, today I work in the office. I’ll try it again at home and reporting the result here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working via vpn uses a different proxy configuration, so I have to modify the .npmrc file each time based on my working location.

Comment: In my case when I read about VPN I realized it could be some network issue, so I decided to try this script, and then it finally worked: npm config set strict-ssl=false;
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/;